# Bind dinâmico com prepare()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou fazendo uma função usando o PDO, quando tento usar o método PREPARE a função não termina com exito, substitui o PREPARE pelo QUERY mudando alguns argumentos e deu certo.

Mas minha dúvida é a seguinte porque que com o PREPARE não está dando certo?

```
function create($tabela, array $dados){

    $campos = implode(", ", array_keys($dados));
    $values = "'".implode("', '", array_values($dados))."'";

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=curso','root','');

    try{
        $operacao = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabela (?) VALUES (?)");
        $operacao->bindValue(1,$campos);
        $operacao->bindValue(1,$values);
        $operacao->execute();
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'Erro '.$e->getMessage();
    }

    if($operacao->rowCount()>0){
        return true;
    }else{
        echo "Não Cadastrou";
    }

};

$evento = array('id_cliente' => 81, 'nome_cliente' => 'Marcos', 'idade' => 32);
create('clientes',$evento);
```

Comment: Você provavelmente não vai ter um campo chamado "nome,endereço,telefone" na sua tabela, mas está tentando dar bind nele. A sintaxe do `bindValue` é `bindValue ( mixed $parameter , mixed $value [, int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR ] )`, não dá para passar uma coleção de campos assim.

Comment: Você não pode dar bind em nomes de colunas apenas em valores.

Comment: Olá Amigos, porém mesmo se eu tente. Só da Bind nos valores não da certo,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A forma mais prática de fazer um bind dinâmico é contar o número de interrogações passar ele na sql e por último jogar os valores em [execute()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php). usando prepared statemens não é preciso escapar os valores com aspas. Lembre de criar uma rotina que valide/limpe o nome da tabela e da listas de campos para evitar resultados indesejados.

```
function create($tabela, array $dados){

    $campos = implode(", ", array_keys($dados));
    $values = implode(", ", array_values($dados));
    
    $totalInterrogacoes = count($dados);
    
    $interrogacoes = str_repeat('?,', $totalInterrogacoes);
    $interrogacoes = substr($interrogacoes, 0, -1); // remove a última virgula
    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tabela($campos) VALUES($interrogacoes)";
    $operacao = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    
    $operacao->execute($values);
    
}
```

Fica ao seu critério passar a chave primária(e o seu valor) ou não no array de campos/valores, caso passe ele é necessario sempre cortar o indice zero de `$campos`e `$values`.

[**Exemplo simplificado**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/35e1-ya3q)

Comment: Cara, sensacional. Obrigado!

Comment: Olá @perdeu, cara seu exemplo realmente resolveu o meu problema e pude aprender com ele, porém ele nao funcionou quando usei o Trecho $operacao->execute($values); - Talvez porque o Execute espera receber um array como argumento aew quando coloquei esse trecho no lugar daquele deu certo, coloquei assim - $operacao->execute(array_values($dados)); Estou certo meu amigo? Fiquei com duvidas! Obrigado.

Comment: Sim ele espera um array, na operação de delete/update você pode por chamar assim `$operacao->execute(array($id));`. O que você está certo.