# Como fazer com que a variável id não se repita no loop?

Tags: php, array, foreach

Estou tentando receber um `array` associativo como argumento deste métodos, na verdade recebe um `array` no primeiro argumento e um valor numérico no segundo.

Minha dúvida é como fazer com que a variável `$id` não se repita?

Pois está a dar esse erro:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]:
>   SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables
>   does not match number of tokens in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.8.0\www\connect\standardModel.php on line 92

Fonte:

```
<?php
public function update($data = array(), $id)
{
    if (is_array($data) && count($data) > 0 && $id != false)
    {
        $sql = "update `{$this->table}` set ";

        foreach($data as $key => $value)
        {
            $sql .= $key . " = ?, ";
        }

        $sql = substr($sql, 0, - 2);
        $sql .= "where id = ?";

        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        foreach($data as $value)
        {
            $query->bindValue($value . ",",$id);
        }

        if ($query->execute()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Pode fazer um bind dinâmico passando os valores no execute http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33524/91

Comment: A últimas linhas (todo o `if`) podem ser simplificadas para `return $query->execute();`. Não complique o que é simples.

Answer (score 1):

Bem, não sei se isso vai te ajudar, mas já fiz isso uma vez da seguinte forma:

```
public static function update($tabela, $dados, $condicao = NULL){
    $sql = 'UPDATE '.$tabela.' SET ';
    foreach($dados as $key => $value):
        $campos[] = $key.'=?';
        $valores[] = $value;
    endforeach;
    $sql .= implode(', ', $campos);
    if(!is_null($condicao)) $sql .= ' WHERE '.$condicao;
    try{
        $query = self::$conexao->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($valores);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        self::erroLog(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Explicando:

`$tabela` eu passo a tabela onde será feito o update.
`$dados` é meu array que contem os dados.
`$condicao` é onde eu deixo como `null` por padrão para atualizar toda a tabela, no seu caso
para atualizar um `id` específico você pode passar ele como paramêtro.

Ex:

`update('tabelaCarros', $arrayDados, 'id=2');`

Código completo no [GitHub](https://github.com/IsaiasD/ArquivosPHP/blob/master/PDO/Banco.model.php)

Answer (score 1):

Essa mensagem aparece quando a consulta, quando que o número de colunas é diferente do de valores ou seja valores a mais e colunas de menos ou o contrário, no seu código a maneira que demanda menos alterações é atribuir um indíce `id` no em `$data` **após** a montagem da sql, uma variável de controle `$i` é necessária para informar o número de interrogação combinará com qual valor(`$value`)

O código alterado ficará dessa forma:

```
$sql = substr($sql, 0, - 2);
$sql .= " where id = ?";
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);

$data['id'] = $id;
$i = 1; //indice atual da interrogação. 
foreach($data as $value)
{
   $query->bindValue($i, $value);
   $i++;
}

//simplificação sugerida pelo @Maniero
return $query->execute();
```

Comment: Infelizmente tá complicado, já tentei vários exemplos incluindo o que você postou. Já se passou um dia na tentativa , mas faz parte.

Comment: @valdineyfrança quando colocou o código essa linha estava certa? `$query->bindValue($value . ",",$id);` tem uma concatenação de uma virgula inválida