# Como usar PDO bindParam no IN() da query?

Tags: php, pdo

Tenho uma query similar a esta:

```
$modelos = "1,2,3,4";
$sql = "Select codigo_modelo, nome From modelos Where codigo_modelo in (:codigo_modelo)"                
$sql->bindParam(":codigo_modelo",$modelos,PDO::PARAM_INT); //TAMBEM JA TENTEI COM PARAM_STR
```

Porém continua me retornando 0 rows.

Fazendo desta outra forma tudo ocorre normalmente:

```
$modelos = "1,2,3,4";
$sql = "Select codigo_modelo, nome From modelos Where codigo_modelo in (".$modelos.")"
```

Alguma idéia? Gostaria de seguir utilizando o `bindParam` por motivos obvios...

Comment: Para cada valor é necessário um placeholder, pode implementar esse mecanismo [dessa forma](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33528/91)

Answer (score 4):

Uma sugestão seria formatar sua string de consulta e depois fazer o `bindParam` para cada parâmetro, exemplo:

```
    $modelos = explode(",","1,2,3,4"); // transforma string em array
    $query = sprintf("Select codigo_modelo, nome From modelos Where codigo_modelo in (%s)",
            implode(
            ',',
            array_map(
                function() {
                   static $x = 0;
                   return ':cod_'.$x++;
                },$modelos
            )
        )
    );
```

Isto irá [formatar sua string de consulta](http://ideone.com/TCIjzf) da seguinte forma:

```
Select codigo_modelo, nome From modelos Where codigo_modelo in (:cod_0,:cod_1,:cod_2,:cod_3)
```

Assim você poderá percorrer o array e fazer `bindParam` dos parâmetros

```
    $sql = $conexao->prepare($query);
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($modelos); $i++){
        $sql->bindParam(":cod_".$i,$modelos[$i]); //$sql->bindParam(":cod_0",1) ...;
    }
    $sql->execute();
```

Answer (score 4):

Para cada valor na consulta é necessario informar o respectivo named/placholder, a forma como você passou o valor(`1,2,3,4`) o PDO entendeu isso como um unico valor representado por `:cod_modelo`.

Uma forma de realizar bind dinamico é saber o número do parametros, criar uma string com *n* interrogações e concatenar elas na consulta dentro da clásula IN. 
Os valores devem ser passados no `execute()` como um array e não mais de forma individual com `bindParam()`

```
$dados = array(1,2,3,4);
$totalInterrogacoes = count($dados);

$interrogacoes = str_repeat('?,', $totalInterrogacoes);
$interrogacoes = substr($interrogacoes, 0, -1); // remove a última virgula

$cmd = "SELECT * FROM modelos WHERE codigo_modelo in($interrogacoes)";
$stmt = $sql->prepare($cmd);
$stmt->execute($dados);

$operacao->execute($values);
```