# Diferença entre o prepare() e o query()?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Eu estava fazendo um `select` em uma tabela.

Fui ver o resultado, retornou false. Depois usei o `query` e deu certo.

Qual a diferença entre os dois?

```
<?php
   $query = DB::getConn()->prepare('select * from tabela where id in ('.$id.')');

   /*o prepare retornou false*/

   $query = DB::getConn()->query('select * from tabela where id in ('.$id.')');
 ?>
```

Comment: Está usando o PDO?

Comment: Sim @rray tudo pela segurança

Answer (score 11):

`prepare()` utiliza prepared statements uma fez feita a consulta ela é otimizada pelo banco e pode ser executada N vezes o que muda são os argumentos, seu uso evita problema com sql injection desde que usado corretamente.

`query()` realiza uma consulta simples, a cada chamada uma consulta é enviada para o banco, ao utilizar esse método o programador é responsável por sanitizar os valores passados.

Ambos retornam false, caso a consulta falhe, para obter mais detalhes sobre o erro chama o método [errorInfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php).

O uso correto seria, definir uma intorrogação para cada valor e passar um array para `execute()` por praticidade, isso também pode ser feito com `bindValue()` ou `bindParam()` caso exista alguma necessidade.

obs: com o código das duas primeiras linhas pode ser criado um método a parte somente para gerar as interrogações.

```
$ids = array(1,2,5,8);
$binds = implode(",", array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));

$query = DB::getCon()->prepare('select * from tabela where id in ('. $binds .')' );
$query->execute($ids);
```

Caso queira compara apenas com id, pode simplificar dessa forma.

```
$query = DB::getCon()->prepare('select * from tabela where id = ?');
$query->execute(array(1));
//a partir do php5.4
//$query->execute([1]);
```

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Por que consultas SQL parametrizadas(nome = ?) previnem SQL Injection?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63447/91)

[Usar PDO é a maneira mais segura de se conectar a um BD com PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68232/91)

[Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/91)

[Como usar PDO bindParam no IN() da query?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58123/91)

[Bind dinâmico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33524/91)

Comment: ótima resposta!

Answer (score 4):

### Query()

> Com a função `$stmt->query()` as consultas são executadas juntamente com os valores nela passados, sem quaisquer tratamentos interno, sendo que, a parte de tratar desses valores de modo a torná-los seguros para a consulta, são deixados à escolha do programador. Se no caso você não irá passar parâmetros como GET ou POST, etc... esta é uma boa opção.

### Prepare( )

A função `$stmp->prepare()`, é chamada de "Prepare Instatement" (Instruções preparadas).

A declaração preparada é um recurso usado para executar as mesmas (ou similares) instruções SQL repetidamente com alta eficiência. Declarações preparadas trabalham basicamente assim:

> **Prepare**: Um modelo de instrução SQL é criado e enviado ao banco de dados. Certos valores não são especificados, chamados de parâmetros do tipo placeholder (identificado como "?" ou ":variavel").

Por exemplo: `INSERT INTO TABELA VALUES (?,?,?)`

O banco de dados analisa, compila e executa uma consulta otimizada no modelo de instrução SQL e armazena o resultado sem executá-lo.

Segue 4 exemplos de utilização com **prepare statment** através do objeto [**PDO**](http://br.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php):

```
    <?php
    /* Example one: Execute a prepared statement with placeholder */
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO tabela (cod, nome, email) VALUES (:codigo, :nome, :email)';

    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute(array(':codigo' => (int) 128,
                        ':nome' => 'ndroid',
                        ':email' => 'ndroid@gmail.com'));

  /* Example two: Execute a prepared statement with bind param method */
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO tabela (cod, nome, email) VALUES (:codigo, :nome, :email)';

    $valor1 = '128';
    $valor2 = 'ndroid';
    $valor3 = 'ndroid@gmail.com';

    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindParam(":codigo", $valor1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->bindParam(":nome", $valor2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindParam(":email", $valor3, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->execute();

 /* Example three: Execute a prepared statement with bind value method */
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO tabela (cod, nome, email) VALUES (:codigo, :nome, :email)';

    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindValue(":codigo", (int) 128, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->bindValue(":nome", 'ndroid', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(":email", 'ndroid@gmail.com', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->execute();

 /* Example four: Execute a prepared statement with sequence */
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO tabela (cod, nome, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';

    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute(array((int) 128,
                        'ndroid',
                        'ndroid@gmail.com'));
    ?>
```

> **Execute:** Após receber a query preparada, a aplicação liga os valores com os parâmetros associados, e o banco de dados executa a instrução. 
>   O sistema pode executar a declaração tantas vezes quanto ele quer com valores diferentes. Em comparação com a execução de instruções SQL diretamente.

**Declarações preparadas têm duas vantagens principais:**

1. declarações preparadas reduz o tempo de análise como a preparação em que a consulta é feita apenas uma vez, embora a instrução é executada várias vezes,
   parâmetros vinculados minimizam a largura de banda para o servidor como você precisa enviar apenas os parâmetros de cada vez, e não toda a consulta.
2. declarações preparadas são muito úteis contra injeções de SQL, porque os valores dos parâmetros, que são transmitidos posteriormente usam protocolo diferente, não precisa ser corretamente escapado, por métodos como `strip_tags()`, `preg_replace()`, etc. Se o modelo de declaração original não é derivado de entrada externa, a injeção de SQL não irá ocorrer.

[**- Para saber mais da função Query**](http://br.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)
[**- Para saber mais da função Prepare**](http://br.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: Agora sim, +1 pela resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando o método `prepare()`, os valores para a consulta são passados através de parâmetros, que são tratados parcialmente à consulta. Consultas utilizando este método são preferíveis quando os parâmetros desejados são dinâmicos.

Com o método `query()` as consultas são executadas juntamente com os valores nela passados, sem quaisquer tratamentos interno, sendo que, a parte de tratar desses valores de modo a torna-los seguros para a consulta, são deixados à escolha do programador.

Utilizando as *prepared statments* com o `PDO` pode-se usar dois tipos de *placeholders* ou parâmetros:

- O ponto de interrogação ( ? ).
- O dois pontos seguido do nome do parâmetro desejado ( :nome ).

Não se pode usar os dois tipos de parâmetros na mesma consulta *SQL*, deve-se escolher um, e usar apenas esse parâmetro na consulta atual, sendo que os valores passados, não devem ser executados diretamente na consulta.

Outra coisa é o facto que que o *PDO* vai emular as *prepared statments* para os drivers não suportados por ele nativamente, e nem todos os drivers suportam ambos os tipos.

Usando o ponto de interrogação ( **?** ):

```
$query = DB::getConn()->prepare('select * from tabela where id in (?)');
$query->execute(array(1));
```

Usando o parâmetro nomeado ( **:nome** ):

```
$query = DB::getConn()->prepare('select * from tabela where id in (:nome)');
$query->execute(array(':nome'=>1));
```

Usando o ponto de interrogação para um número de parâmetros desconhecido:

```
$values = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,...n);

foreach ($values as $val)
{
    $params[] = '?';
}

$query = DB::getConn()->prepare('select * from tabela where id in ('.implode(",", $params).')');
$query->execute($values);
```

Várias entradas, para 2 campos específicos da tabela SQL:

```
foreach($values as $id=>$val){
$params[] = '(?, ?)';
$binds['campo1' . $i] = $val; 
$binds['campo2' . $i] = $val;   
$i++;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO x (campo1, campo2) VALUES ". implode(",", $params);
```

Ou ainda, vários parâmetros nomeados, para 2 campos específicos da tabela SQL:

```
foreach($values as $id=>$val){
    $params[] = '(:campo1' . $i . ', :campo2' . $i . ')';
    $binds['campo1' . $i] = $val; 
    $binds['campo2' . $i] = $val;   
    $i++;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO x (campo1, campo2) VALUES ". implode(",", $params);
```

**Algumas referências:**

[Writing MySQL script with PHP and PDO](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html)

[PDO Prepared Statments - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepare.php)

[PDO Query - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.query.php)

Answer (score 1):

Prepare apenas prepara uma instrução e retorna um *resource* chamado de *Prepared Statement*, ou seja, um objeto de instrução SQL pré compilado que aguarda apenas ser executado.

Query executa uma instrução e retorna um *resource* que é um ponteiro para um *resultset*.

Prepare é útil para evitar problemas com argumentos (não só SQL injection) e permite uma melhor utilização para instruções que precisem ser executadas repetidas vezes, aumentando em muito a performance.

No seu código

```
$query = DB::getConn()->prepare('select * from tabela where id in ('.$id.')');
```

não seria tão útil, pois o argumento já está inserido na string de consulta.

Usar Prepared Statement tem desvantagens na hora de fazer debug, pois você não conseguirá recuperar exatamente a Instrução SQL com os argumentos preenchidos.