# Consulta em branco

Tags: sql, query

Estou iniciando no mundo da programação e de inicio estou com um problema quado executo a query localmente a consulta me mostra o retorno normalmente porém quando tento fazer a consulta através de uma aplicação simples:

```
<?php
/**
 * 
 * @var string $dsn  : driver de conexão : endereco do servidor : nome do banco
 * @var string $user : usuario do banco
 * @var string $pass : senha do usuario 
 */
$dsn = 'odbc:driver={SQL Server};server=IP_DO_SERVIDOR;database=TESTE';
$user = 'xxxxxxx';
$pass = 'xxxxxxx';

try 
{
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn,$user,$pass);
}
catch(PDOException $exeption)
{
   die("Erro: $exeption");
}

// Definindo o mode de erros da classe
//$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$select = "SELECT * FROM FIN_TITULO WHERE EMPRESA = 1 AND REVENDA = 1 AND TITULO = 435376";

$result = $pdo->exec($select);

var_dump($result);
```

o `var_dump` retorna o valor 0, ou seja, nenhuma linha afetada, não sei o que fazer, seria talvez permissão do usuário pois a consulta direta através do SQL management funciona normalmente?

Answer (score 0):

Tente dessa forma:

```
$result = $pdo->query($select);
```

ou

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM FIN_TITULO WHERE EMPRESA = 1 AND REVENDA = 1 AND TITULO = 435376";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($select);
$statement->execute();

// Verifica e gera array assoc
if($statement->rowCount()) {
    $stt = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($stt);
}
```

> Opa funcionou, só não entendi porque o resultado da minha consulta
>   inicial não tinha retorno – Guilherme Arantes

Ao usar `PDO::EXEC` o resultado retornado não é um `PDOStatement`, e sim um inteiro das linhas afetadas.

Ao usar `PDO::QUERY` o resultado retornado é um `PDOStatement`.

Fontes:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978481/pdoexec-or-pdoquery) [2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92400/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-prepare-e-o-query)

Comment: meu problema não é referente a conexão e sim com a consulta o retorno exibido no var_dump ainda é 'int(0)' deveria ser 'int(1)'

Comment: @GuilhermeArantes atualizada. Desculpe a confusão

Comment: Opa funcionou, só não entendi porque o resultado da minha consulta inicial não tinha retorno

Comment: Você pode tentar verificar assim: `$db->exec($select) or die(print_r($db->errorInfo(), true));`, dessa for irá exibir o erro para você debugar. Também pode usar o `$db->query($select)`.