# duvida sobre metodo POST

Tags: php, formulário, post

Estou aprendendo php e gostaria de tirar uma duvida se meu código está vulnerável a sql injection.

No caso estou montando um formulário

```
<form method="POST" action="classes/cliente.class.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input class="input" type="text" name="razaosocial" placeholder="Razão Social" onkeyup="maiuscula(this)">
<button class="button is-primary" type="submit" value="Cadastrar" name="novoCliente">CADASTRAR</button>
```

ai no outro arquivo estou pegando da seguinte maneira

```
   if (array_key_exists("novoCliente", $_POST)){ 
$razaosocial       = $_POST["razaosocial"];
$sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO cliente VALUES ('', '".$razaosocial."') ");
            if ($sql){
                echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='../consultaCliente.php'</script>";
                }
                else{
                echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Erro no cadastro!');window.location.href='../cadastroCliente.php'</script>";
                }
else
echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='../cadastroUsuario.php'</script>";
```

Isso é certo? Está vulnerável?

Comment: Fique de olho sempre ao lidar com entrada do usuário. Entradas de usuário são perigosas, pois são vetores de ataque. SQL é uma linguagem poderosa (afinal ela controla seu banco de dados) e você enfiou entrada de usuário no meio dela sem "higienizar", está dando bastante poder para o usuário, que pode ser um invasor. A regra de ouro é: "higienize toda a entrada de usuário" (sanitize all user input).

Answer (score 3):

Sim, é vulnerável. Você pode perceber isso através dessas duas linhas:

```php
$razaosocial = $_POST["razaosocial"];
$sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO cliente VALUES ('', '".$razaosocial."') ");
```

Imagine se a pessoa enviar como parâmetro `razaosocial` o valor `Luiz`. O comando SQL seria:

```sql
INSERT INTO clientes VALUES ('', 'Luiz')
```

Certo? Agora imagine se a pessoa colocasse como valor o seguinte:

```
Luiz'); DROP TABLE clientes; --
```

A *query* completa ficaria:

```sql
INSERT INTO clientes VALUES ('', 'Luiz'); DROP TABLE clientes; -- ')
```

E isso é só um dos exemplos.

---

Para prevenir isso, o mais ideal é que você *[prepared statements](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/138739/69296)*.

Existem diversas formas de se preparar um *statement*. Você pode usar o próprio [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli.php) (através do [`prepare`](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.prepare.php)) ou usar outras bibliotecas, como o [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php).

Comment: Por que a forma mais fácil é usar PDO, se ele já usa mysqli?

Comment: Na minha opinião a forma de se preparar no PDO é mais simples do que no MySQLi. Preferência pessoal. De todo modo, editei a resposta para dizer que também é possível ser feito no MySQLi.

Comment: Acho que o próprio PHP recomenta o PDO. Pois tudo que é digitado no campo vira texto comum e não faz parte do código.

Comment: pesquisando aqui cheguei nisso... agora desta forma é seguro?

if (array_key_exists("cadastro", $_POST)){ 


$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO teste (nome) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['nome']);
$stmt->execute();
//fetching result would go here, but will be covered later
$stmt->close();


}
else
 echo "ERRO";

Comment: tambem podes usar o addslashes na variável que queres enviar