# Busca com MySQL PDO em Array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho esse código:

```
$whereBusca = "itaim-bibi";
$whereBusca  = explode(',', $whereBusca);
$sql = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, nome, caminho FROM regiao WHERE caminho IN (:whereBusca)');
$sql->execute(array("whereBusca" => "'".implode("','", $whereBusca)."'"));
$resultadoSql = $sql->fetchAll();
foreach ($resultadoSql as $valorSql) {
    echo utf8_encode($valorSql['id']);
}
```

Ele funciona bem, mas se o conteudo do $whereBusca for mais que uma região, ele não da o search, não sei o que estou errando, olha o exemplo de quando não funciona:

```
$whereBusca = "itaim-bibi,jardins";
$whereBusca  = explode(',', $whereBusca);
$sql = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, nome, caminho FROM regiao WHERE caminho IN (:whereBusca)');
$sql->execute(array("whereBusca" => "'".implode("','", $whereBusca)."'"));
$resultadoSql = $sql->fetchAll();
foreach ($resultadoSql as $valorSql) {
    echo utf8_encode($valorSql['id']);
}
```

Comment: Veja se com aspas muda algo: `array("whereBusca" => "'".implode("','", $whereBusca)."'" )`

Comment: Oi, também não.... até entendi o que pensou, pra ficar assim né? "'itaim-bibi','jardin'"
Mas não rola tb...

Comment: Na verdade foi a unica coisa que eu pensei, pra dar explode e implode em seguida. Não sei se nesse caso o PREPARE é o melhor caminho para resolver o problema. Eu andei postando umas respostas no site que fazem um WHERE mais complexo, com um LIKE '%%' pra cada termo, talvez seja legal vc dar uma espiada. (talvez seja exagero tambem). O ideal seria você dar uns print_r em lugares estratégicos do código para analisar as variáveis, para ver se não tem espaço sobrando ou caracteres a mais ou a menos.

Comment: Veja se alguma te ajuda, tem umas 3 versões parecidas perdidas por aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A70+where+like

Comment: Pode ser que o PDO esteja sanitizando as aspas (bem provável). Seria o caso de montar a string manualmente mesmo. O problema é que você teria que evitar sql injection por sua conta, no caso.

Comment: Vo até ja deixar na pergunta com as aspas d jeito que falou, que acho que é o "correto", como seria essa forma manual?

Comment: Você não pode passar 1 placeholder e N valores, precisar ser na mesma proporção ou seja 1 placeholder para 1 valor. [Como usar PDO bindParam no IN() da query?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58123/91)

Comment: Esse campo tem os vários valores separados por  vírgulas ?

Comment: Quais campos? Do banco de dados?

Comment: Pelo visto é isso que vocês falaram mesmo, valeu, agora to la luta aqui pra fazer o loop pra cada valor da consulta... Ta dureza!

Comment: E se fizer assim: 'SELECT id, nome, caminho FROM regiao WHERE caminho IN ("itaim-bibi","jardins")'

Comment: Conseguiu acertar o `in()` qual é o problema agora?

Comment: @rray é que não sou o maior expert do mundo, to tentando usar o exemplo que você passou, mas ta treta....

Comment: `$whereBusca` é um array certo? e o número de elementos pode variar

Comment: Isso, de 1 a 400 (são 400 regiões no banco de dados), vem como string pq pego via GET, mas transformo em array com explode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é possível definir 1 placeholder para N valores, a proporção deve ser a mesma ou seja, 1 placeholder para 1 valor.

Para fazer um `IN` com um número de parâmetros dinâmicos conte o número de elemento do array, gera um string com o número certo de  placeholders depois joguei isso na consulta e passe um array para `execute()`

```
$valores = ['itaim-bibi','jardins', 'Doge island'];
$n = count($valores);

$placeholders = '?'. str_repeat(',?', $n - 1); //no exemplo a string gerada é ?,?,?

$consulta = "SELECT id, nome, caminho FROM regiao WHERE caminho IN ($placeholders)";
$sql = $pdo->prepare($consulta);
$sql->execute($valores);
```

A SQL gerada é algo como:

```
SELECT id, nome, caminho FROM regiao WHERE caminho IN (?,?,?)
```

3 elementos no array, 3 interrogações ;)

Comment: Perfeito! Só troca la a variavel $interrogacao por placeholders. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @caiocafardo, obrigado pela correção :D não tinha notado.

Comment: @Bacco, otima sugestão vou adicionar ela, outra forma que tinha pensado era `implode(',', array_fill(0, $n, '?'));` ... parece mais custosa.

Answer (score -2):

E se fizer assim:

```
'SELECT id, nome, caminho FROM regiao WHERE caminho IN ("itaim-bibi","jardins")'
```

Ai não precisaria do explode e do implode

Comment: É que to usando PDO, e esse valor "itaim-bibi", "jardins" é só um exemplo.

A busca pode ser feita para 1 região ou para 400, depende do usuário...