# Como trabalhar com a instrução IN no PHP + PDO?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Estou tentando montar um SQL dinamico mas estou apanhando por não entender como trabalhar com a instrução IN no PDO
Exemplo:

```
$SQL = "select * from tabela where (campo in(:valor))";
$Query = Database::Prepare($SQL);
$Query->bindValue(":valor", "1,2");
$Query->Execute();
```

Campo é Integer, eu pressupunha que 1,2 entraria sem problemas como valor, mas ele diz que a pesquisa o valor é inválida, tentei de varias formas mas sem sucesso

Como trabalhar com essa instrução no PDO?
Como quebra galho usei a instrução OR, mas convenhamos não é a melhor opção!
O Banco de Dados é Postgres, mas acho que não vem ao caso, pois não consegui no MySQL também

Comment: [Busca com MySQL PDO em Array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/104696/91)

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi o seu código não funcionou, correto ?

Tente usar um nome por valor:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo IN (:valor1, :valor2, :valor3)";
$Query = Database::Prepare($SQL);
$Query->bindValue(":valor1", "1");
$Query->bindValue(":valor2", "2");
$Query->bindValue(":valor3", "3");
$Query->Execute();
```

Creio que a maneira mais fácil e rápida para você fazer seu código.

**@EDIT**

Uma solução também seria essa:

```
<?php
$ids     = array(1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9); //Valores de cada nome
$inQuery = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));

$Query = Database::Prepare(
    'SELECT *
     FROM tabela
     WHERE campo IN (' . $inQuery . ')'
);


foreach ($ids as $k => $id)
    $Query->bindValue(($k+1), $id);

$Query->execute();
?>
```

Comment: Eu prefiro essa resposta, porque previne ataques de **injeção de SQL de segunda ordem**, ao não passar os valores do array direto para a *query*. Parabéns pela bela resposta. +1

Comment: Eu até pensei em usar explode, mas achei que tivesse uma maneira mais elegante de se trabalhar a clausula IN com PDO

Comment: É @Marcelo, vai ter vezes que temos que trabalhar de um jeito menos elegante por causa desses conflitos em certas coisas no PHP.