# Não salvar Array de valor 0 no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

galera, estou com um formulário com 'n' quantidades de inputs, todas com a mesma estrutura:

```
echo "<input name='quantidade[]' type='number'>";
```

Quando finalizo o formulário e envio pra próxima página, elas chegam pra mim em array, e eu uso esse array pra salvar os dados em um Banco de dados MySQL, uso esse método pra salvar no banco:

```
for( $i=0; $i<count($_POST['item']); $i++ ) {


    // insere no banco
    $PDO = db_connect();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO carrinho(quantidade) VALUES ('".$_POST['quantidade'][$i]."')";
    $stmt = $PDO->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':quantidade', $_POST['quantidade'][$i]  );

    if ($stmt->execute())
    {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Erro ao cadastrar";
        print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
    } 

}
```

Ele salva tudo, e os dados que não tem nenhuma value no INPUT ele salva com o valor 0, queria saber como faço pra não salvar os Arrays com valor "0".

Comment: Se tiver mais de um registro o segundo não insere pq já redireciona. Não deveria colocar o valor direto na sql deveria usar o placeholder definido (`:quantidade`).

Comment: O laço de repetição não vai deixar ele atualizar, e não consegui colocar o array em placeholder definido. Ta salvando todos os registros, perfeitamente, só que tá salvando os valores 0 do array, única coisa que eu não queria!

Comment: Se quer apenas não inserir o valor zero, pode fazer um `if($_POST['quantidade'][$i] > 0){....`. veja que seua conexão é feita N vezes pq esta dentro do laço deveria estar fora. Se quiser mandar tudo em um unico insert veja [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/104696/91)

Comment: Isso mesmo, assim deu certo Vlw, eu tava tentando escrever algo desse tipo e num consegui, OBRIGADO. Mas o insert é pra ser feito 'n' numero de vezes mesmo, esse vai ser o meu carrinho, onde vai ficar os dados temporários dos itens que estão no carrinho do cliente.