# Utilizar prepared statements do PDO em função

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, pdo

Andei lendo sobre prevenção de *sql injections* e vi que utilizar dos *prepared statements* pode ajudar nisso.

Tenho a seguinte função em uma classe para crud que desenvolvi:

```
public function inserir($tabela, $campos, $dados) {
    try {
        $campos = implode(", ", $campos);
        $dados = implode(", ", $dados);

        $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO " .$tabela. " (" .$campos. ") VALUES (" .$dados. ")");

        return $sql->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Ocorreu um erro: " .$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

E, para utiliza-la apenas faço como no exemplo abaixo:

```
$teste = array("nome", "sobrenome", "email");
$testeR = array("'Igor'", "'Teste'", "'i@hotmail.com'");
$bd -> inserir("tabela", $teste, $testeR);
```

E funciona corretamente.

Porém, gostaria de utilizar `bindValue`, mas não sei como proceder.
A única "ideia" de que tenho é que terei que fazer um foreach para cada item, mas realmente não tenho ideia de como farei isso. Como fazer da maneira correta?

**Obrigado!**

**EDITADO**

Modifiquei algumas coisas de acordo com a resposta abaixo (do @rray) e meu código ficou assim:

Na classe:

```
public function inserir($tabela, $dados) {
    try {
        $campos = implode(", ", array_keys($dados));
        $valores = implode(", ", array_values($dados));

        $totalInterrogacoes = count($dados);

        $interrogacoes = str_repeat("?,", $totalInterrogacoes);
        $interrogacoes = substr($interrogacoes, 0, -1); // remove a última virgula

        $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO " .$tabela. " (" .$campos. ") VALUES (" .$interrogacoes. ")");

        var_dump($sql);
        //return $sql->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Ocorreu um erro: " .$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

E em outro arquivo para teste:

```
$teste = array("nome" => "Igor", "sobrenome" => "Teste", "email" => "i@hotmail.com");
$bd -> inserir("tabela", $teste);
```

Então funciona corretamente, e o `var_dump($sql)` me retorna o seguinte:

> object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) {
>     ["queryString"]=>
>     string(58) "INSERT INTO tabela (nome, sobrenome, email) VALUES (?,?,?)"
>   }

Porém, agora surge a grande dúvida novamente: Como efetuar o `bindValue` de cada interrogação para seu respectivo valor?

Comment: Para usar prepared statements vc precisar trocar os valores pelos placeholders, pode ver isso nessa resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33528/91

Comment: Dei uma olhada na resposta do link que vc passou. Porém não entendi uma coisa: o que ele está fazendo é o mesmo que chamar a `bindValue`?

Comment: Editei a pergunta. Espero que possa ajudar. Obrigado!

Comment: @Igor, será realizada substituição do '?' pelos valores presentes dentro do array que é passado no execute mas você pode fazer um foreach sobre o array que será passado e escapar todos os valores.

Comment: Então, @ricardo_henrique. Estou tentando com foreach mas não estou conseguindo. Pode dar um exemplo? Obrigado!

Comment: Quando vc passa um array para o método execute(), eh a mesma coisa que o bindValue(), a primeira interrogação será substituída pelo primeiro elemento do array.

Comment: Ah, entendi @rray! Porém, tentei assim: return $sql->execute($valores); e me retornou o seguinte erro: *:  PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in (na linha do execute)*

Comment: E se eu tentar assim: return $sql->execute(array($valores));
Me retorna o seguinte erro: *Ocorreu um erro: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens*

Comment: O erro diz que o número de interrogações eh diferente da quantia de valores.

Comment: Sim, isso eu entendi, mas não consegui resolver!

Comment: Dei um *var_dump(array($valores));* e o retorno é: *array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "Igor, Teste, i@hotmail.com"
}*
Ou seja, ele está interpretando tudo como 1 item na array apenas. Agora, como posso fazer ele interpretar os 3 itens na array? Será que dando o *explode* de vírgulas e então criando outra array a partir delas seria a maneira correta?

Comment: Na realidade, a minha pergunta já foi respondida. Esse outro caso da array deixarei para outra pergunta. Muito obrigado a todos que colaboraram.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade essa não é a maneira correta.

O PDO do php já oferece suporte ao Bind de variáveis sem que precise editar a query.

Veja o exemplo abaixo. (É um trecho de um serviço que grava dados de GPS em uma tabela no MySql).

```
$Geo = new Geo();
$Geo->latitude = $_GET["latitude"];
$Geo->longitude = $_GET["longitude"];
$Geo->accuracy = $_GET["accuracy"];
$Geo->altitude = $_GET["altitude"];
$Geo->altitudeAccuracy = $_GET["altitudeAccuracy"];
$Geo->heading = $_GET["heading"];
$Geo->speed = $_GET["speed"];
$Geo->timestamp = $_GET["timestamp"];

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=mysql.seudominio.com.br;dbname=baseDeDados", "Usuario", "Senha");
$statement = $pdo->prepare("Insert into geo values(
                                :latitude,
                                :longitude,
                                :accuracy,
                                :altitude,
                                :altitudeAccuracy,
                                :heading,
                                :speed,
                                :timestamp,
                                :now)");
    $statement->bindParam(':latitude', $Geo->latitude);
    $statement->bindParam(':longitude', $Geo->longitude);
    $statement->bindParam(':accuracy', $Geo->accuracy);
    $statement->bindParam(':altitude', $Geo->altitude);
    $statement->bindParam(':altitudeAccuracy', $Geo->altitudeAccuracy);
    $statement->bindParam(':heading', $Geo->heading);
    $statement->bindParam(':speed', $Geo->speed);
    $statement->bindParam(':timestamp', $Geo->timestamp);
    $statement->bindParam(':now', $Geo->now);
    $statement->execute();
```