# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, pdo

> 0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/conexao.php(53): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
>   
> 1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/conexao.php(72): ConexaoDatabase->execute(Object(PDOStatement), Array)
>   
> 2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/pdo_acao.php(122): ConexaoDatabase->save('INSERT INTO bl...', Array)
>   
> 3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/pdo_acao.php(167): PessoasBanco->cadastrarPessoa()
>   
> 4 {main}string(68) "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined"
>   {"codError":"999","message":"Ocorreu um erro no processo!"}

Estou tentando fazer uma inserção no banco e apareceu este erro ao debugar o código javascript. O que pode ser ?

```
public function cadastrarPessoa() {

    $this->data[$this->action] = $this->dadosUpdate();

    if ($this->checkCodSecurity($this->params['lbl_CODCELULA'])) {

        $keys = array_keys($this->data[$this->action]);
        $inputs = implode(', ', $keys);
        $data = array_values($this->data[$this->action]);
        $save = $this->conexao->save("INSERT INTO {$this->tabela } ({preg_replace('/:/','',$inputs)}) VALUES ({$inputs})", $data);

        if ($save) {
            error_log("Entro no salve sucesso!");
            return $this->getMessageView();
        }
        error_log("Entro no salve error!");
        return $this->getMessageView(2);
    }
    return $this->getMessageView(3);
}

private function checkCodSecurity($cod) {
    $data = $this->conexao->fetch("SELECT * FROM tbl_CELULAS WHERE TXT_CODIG_SECUR = :cod", array('cod' => $cod));
    if (!empty($data)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function dadosUpdate() {

    $data = array();

    $linha = $this->conexao->fetch("SELECT * FROM tbl_CELULAS WHERE TXT_CODIG_SECUR = :cod", array('cod' => $this->params['lbl_CODCELULA']));

    $codIgrej = $linha->COD_IDENT_IGREJ;


    //date('Y/m/d',strtotime($this->params['dte_ANIVERSARIO']));  SERVER PARA COLOCAR A DATA NO FORMATO IDEAL PARA O BANCO DE DADOS.

    $data[':COD_IDENT_PESSO'] = 'null'; 
    $data[':COD_IDENT_IGREJ'] = trim($codIgrej); 
    $data[':TXT_NOMEX_PESSO'] = trim($this->params['lbl_NOME']);
    $data[':TXT_APELI_PESSO'] = trim($this->params['lbl_APELIDO']);
    $data[':TXT_FONEX_PESSO'] = trim($this->params['lbl_TELEFONE']);
    $data[':DAT_NASCI_PESSO'] = trim(date('Y/m/d',strtotime($this->params['dte_ANIVERSARIO'])));
    $data[':TXT_NASCI_PESSO'] = 'null';
    $data[':TXT_NATUR_PESSO'] = 'null';
    $data[':FLG_SEXOX_PESSO'] = trim($this->params['lbl_SEXO']);
    $data[':FLG_ESTAD_CIVIL'] = 'null';
    $data[':FLG_IDENT_PESSO'] = 'A';
    $data[':TXT_EMAIL_PESSO'] = trim($this->params['lbl_EMAIL']);
    $data[':TXT_SENHA_USUAR'] = trim($this->params['lbl_SENHA']);
    $data[':TXT_ENDER_CEPXX'] = trim($this->params['lbl_CEP']);
    $data[':SGL_ENDER_ESTAD'] = trim($this->params['lbl_ESTADO']);
    $data[':TXT_ENDER_CIDAD'] = trim($this->params['lbl_CIDADE']);
    $data[':TXT_ENDER_BAIRR'] = trim($this->params['lbl_BAIRRO']);
    $data[':TXT_ENDER_LOGRA'] = trim($this->params['lbl_RUA']);
    $data[':TXT_ENDER_NUMER'] = trim($this->params['lbl_NUMERO']);
    $data[':TXT_ENDER_COMPL'] = trim($this->params['lbl_COMPLEMENTO']);
    $data[':BLO_FOTOX_PESSO'] = 'null';
    $data[':COD_IDULT_ATUAL'] = '-1';
    $data[':DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL'] = date('Y-m-d H:i');
    return $data;
}
if (isset($acao)) {
    if ($acao == 'cadastrar') {
        $actionExecute = new PessoasBanco($_POST, 'cadastrar');
        echo $actionExecute->cadastrarPessoa();
    }
    if ($acao == 'deletar') {

        $actionExecute = new PessoasBanco($_POST, 'deletar');
        echo $actionExecute->deletarPessoa();
    }
    if ($acao == 'verificar') {
        $actionExecute = new PessoasBanco($_POST, 'verificar');
        echo $actionExecute->verificarPessoas();
    }
}
```

Conexão php

```
public function execute(PDOStatement $stmt, array $data = null) {
    try {
        if (isset($data)) {
            $stmt->execute($data);
        } else {
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    } catch (PDOException $exc) {
        error_log($exc->getTraceAsString());
        var_dump($exc->getMessage());
    }
}

/** UPDATE OR INSERT DATA 

 * */
public function save($sql, array $data) {

    $con = self::getConnection();

    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);

    $this->execute($stmt, $data);


    //error_log($stmt->rowCount());

    if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
         error_log("Entrou no row cont da conexao");
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

A Query que retorna(insert chamado em `save()`:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_PESSOAS (
COD_IDENT_PESSO,
COD_IDENT_CELUL,
COD_IDENT_IGREJ,
TXT_NOMEX_PESSO,
TXT_APELI_PESSO,
TXT_FONEX_PESSO,
DAT_NASCI_PESSO,
TXT_NASCI_PESSO,
TXT_NATUR_PESSO,
FLG_SEXOX_PESSO,
FLG_ESTAD_CIVIL,
FLG_IDENT_PESSO,
TXT_EMAIL_PESSO,
TXT_SENHA_USUAR,
TXT_ENDER_CEPXX,
SGL_ENDER_ESTAD,
TXT_ENDER_CIDAD,
TXT_ENDER_BAIRR,
TXT_ENDER_LOGRA,
TXT_ENDER_NUMER,
TXT_ENDER_COMPL,
BLO_FOTOX_PESSO,
COD_IDULT_ATUAL,
DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL)
VALUES (
:COD_IDENT_PESSO,
:COD_IDENT_CELUL,
:COD_IDENT_IGREJ,
:TXT_NOMEX_PESSO,
:TXT_APELI_PESSO,
:TXT_FONEX_PESSO,
:DAT_NASCI_PESSO,
:TXT_NASCI_PESSO,
:TXT_NATUR_PESSO,
:FLG_SEXOX_PESSO,
:FLG_ESTAD_CIVIL,
:FLG_IDENT_PESSO,
:TXT_EMAIL_PESSO,
:TXT_SENHA_USUAR,
:TXT_ENDER_CEPXX,
:SGL_ENDER_ESTAD,
:TXT_ENDER_CIDAD,
:TXT_ENDER_BAIRR,
:TXT_ENDER_LOGRA,
:TXT_ENDER_NUMER,
:TXT_ENDER_COMPL,
:BLO_FOTOX_PESSO,
:COD_IDULT_ATUAL,
:DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL)
```

O Array que vai passar os valores para o sql.

```
Array\n(\n
    [0] => null\n
    [1] => AbC12\n
    [2] => IBA\n
    [3] => Felipe Nunes\n
    [4] => felipe\n
    [5] => 3188488185\n
    [6] => 1993/01/21\n
    [7] => null\n
    [8] => null\n
    [9] => M\n
    [10] => null\n
    [11] => A\n
    [12] => felipe@teste.com\n
    [13] => 555\n
    [14] => 35182392\n
    [15] => MG\n
    [16] => Timoteo\n
    [17] => Timoteo\n
    [18] => Rua 8\n
    [19] => 225\n
    [20] => \n
    [21] => null\n
    [22] => -1\n
    [23] => 2015-08-27 12:53\n
)\n
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54271/discussion-on-question-by-renan-rodrigues-sqlstatehy093-invalid-parameter-num)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Agora o erro mudou se for comparado com a primeira versão da pergunta.

Ao usar named placeholder(`:valor`) o array passado no `execute()` com os valores deve ter as chaves os nomes dos named placeholders.

```
    $keys = array_keys($this->data[$this->action]);//obtem as chaves
    $inputs = implode(', ', $keys);
    $data = array_values($this->data[$this->action]);
   //obtem apenas os valores, um array de indices numericos sera gerado.
```

Para resolver isso, passe os nomes dos named placehords nas chaves de `$data` ou substitua elas por interrogações, dessa forma cada valor será trocado pela interrogação naquela posição, como nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33528/91)

Comment: Cara deu certinho, muito obrigado. Lutamos 3 dias e chegamos a uma solução. Obrigado

Comment: @RenanRodrigues fico feliz que isso resolver o problema :D, [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68238/91) tem umas outras dicas sobre prepared statements e pdo em geral.