# uma forma mais eficiente de fazer o bind de insert e update grande

Tags: php, pdo

```
public function update($table, $data, $where,$criterios)
{

    $set = "";
    foreach ($data as $keyname => $value) {
        $set .= ($set == "") ? "" : ", ";
        $set .= $keyname . " = "  . ":".$keyname ;
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE $table SET $set WHERE $where";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);

    foreach ($data as $placeholder => $valor) {
        $stmt->bindValue(":".$placeholder, $valor);
    }
    foreach ($criterios as $criterio => $valor) {
        $stmt->bindValue(":".$criterio, $valor);
    }
    return $stmt->execute();
}

update("tabelanome",$_POST,"WHERE :id=id",array("id"=>1));
```

há algo que possa ser feito para o código não ser vulnerável?

Comment: O `execute()` é uma boa opção, [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33528/91) tem outra.

Answer (score 1):

Como parâmetro do [`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), você pode informar um array com a relação key/value dos parâmetros do binding. Dessa forma, é só popular o array e passar como parâmetro do método. Exemplo:

```
$bindingArray = array(
    ':bind1' => 'value1', 
    ':bind2' => 'value2'
);

$stmt->execute($bindingArray);
```