# Update em duas tabelas com a mesma função

Tags: php

Possuo uma função que faz um `UPDATE` gostaria de saber se com a mesma função consigo fazer mais que um `UPDATE` por exemplo em 2 tabelas no db. Existe alguma possibilidade ? Gostaria de saber a sintaxe também se existir.

***Código:***

```
public function editar(Prog $prog){
    $this->conn->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare(
            'UPDATE ESP353Prog SET NrProg = :NrProg, DtProg = :DtProg, NrPlaca = :NrPlaca, NrPlacaCarreta = :NrPlacaCarreta, 
            NrPlacaReboque2 = :NrPlacaReboque2,  DsMotorista = :DsMotorista, DsOrigem = :DsOrigem, DsDestino = :DsDestino, QtPesoTtl = :QtPesoTtl
            WHERE ID = :ID');
        $stmt->bindValue(':ID', $prog->getid(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':NrProg', $prog->getprog(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':DtProg', $prog->getdataopr(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':NrPlaca', $prog->getplaca(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':NrPlacaCarreta', $prog->getcarreta(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':NrPlacaReboque2', $prog->getreboque(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':DsMotorista', $prog->getmot(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':DsOrigem', $prog->getorig(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':DsDestino', $prog->getdest(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':QtPesoTtl', $prog->getpesottl(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $this->conn->commit();
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        $this->conn->rollback();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sim é possível, o quei vai mudar são o nome da tabela e os campos. Tem um exemplo [nessa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33528/91).

Comment: Terá que mudar muita coisa no método, como a montagem da SQL e os `bindValue`, quando estava iniciando no PHP criei uma biblioteca de crud básica, basta fazer download, executar o .sql e abrir o index no localhost pra ler a introdução: https://github.com/LeonardoVilarinho/MinPDO

Comment: Deve estar à procura de http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php