# PHP inserir uma array de dados em uma tabela mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Eu possuo uma array em php que contém alguns dados, exemplo:

```
Array
(
    [nome] => Nome
    [sobrenome] => Sobrenome
    [genero] => 1
    [email] => email@mail.com
)
```

E gostaria de inserir esses dados em uma tabela mySql de modo mais automático. No momento em que gero essa array, já é feito o processo para que fique de acordo com a tabela, ou seja, minha tabela é composta pelas colunas `nome`, `sobrenome`, `genero` e `email`.

Então, ao invés de fazer uma query assim:

```
INSER INTO tabela (nome, sobrenome, genero, email) VALUES ('$nome', ...)
```

Gostaria de saber se existe algum método de automatizar essa execução com base na array de dados que possuo.

Pensei em executar algum processo para tratar essa array da seguinte maneira:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value){
    $keys   = $keys.$key.",";
    $values = $values.$values.",";
}
$keys   = substr($keys, 0,-1);
$values = substr($values, 0,-1);

INSER INTO tabela ('$keys') VALUES ('$values');
```

Mas não sei se é o mais adequado/ideal e/ou se existe um método "correto" de se executar essa tarefa.

Comment: [sugestão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33528/91)

Comment: @rray parece que com `array_keys` e `array_values` eu consigo simplificar o código que usei como sugestão, correto?

Comment: Sim é uma forma de resolver o problema só não esqueça que as chaves do array devem ter os mesmo nomes das colunas.

Comment: @rray isso eu já estou fazendo justamente para tentar automatizar ao máximo esse processo.

Comment: @DanielOmine blz, valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Bom esta não é nem de longe a melhor solução, só estou lhe dando um norte, porém o ideal seria ter escapes no valor para evitar SQL Injection, então esta é só uma forma reduzida. ah! não testei.

```
$data = array(
    'nome' => 'Nome',
    'sobrenome' => 'Sobrenome',
    'genero' => 1,
    'email' => 'email@mail.com'
);

$sql = sprintf(
    "INSERT INTO tabela (%s) VALUES ('%s');",
    implode(',', array_keys($data)),
    implode("','", array_values($data))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

No osCommerce tem uma função que faz justamente isso que você precisa e tem até alguns recursos bem bacaninhas, basta adaptar no seu projeto ou analisar o código e fazer algo parecido:

```
// função principal
function tep_db_perform($table, $data, $action = 'insert', $parameters = '', $link = 'db_link') {
    reset($data);
    if ($action == 'insert') {
      $query = 'insert into ' . $table . ' (';
      while (list($columns, ) = each($data)) {
        $query .= $columns . ', ';
      }
      $query = substr($query, 0, -2) . ') values (';
      reset($data);
      while (list(, $value) = each($data)) {
        switch ((string)$value) {
          case 'now()':
            $query .= 'now(), ';
            break;
          case 'null':
            $query .= 'null, ';
            break;
          default:
            $query .= '\'' . tep_db_input($value) . '\', ';
            break;
        }
      }
      $query = substr($query, 0, -2) . ')';
    } elseif ($action == 'update') {
      $query = 'update ' . $table . ' set ';
      while (list($columns, $value) = each($data)) {
        switch ((string)$value) {
          case 'now()':
            $query .= $columns . ' = now(), ';
            break;
          case 'null':
            $query .= $columns .= ' = null, ';
            break;
          default:
            $query .= $columns . ' = \'' . tep_db_input($value) . '\', ';
            break;
        }
      }
      $query = substr($query, 0, -2) . ' where ' . $parameters;
    }
    return tep_db_query($query, $link);
}

// Funções chamadas
function tep_db_query($query, $link = 'db_link') {
    global $$link;
    $result = mysqli_query($$link, $query) or tep_db_error($query, mysqli_errno($$link), mysqli_error($$link));
    return $result;
}

function tep_db_input($string, $link = 'db_link') {
    global $$link;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($$link, $string);
}

function tep_db_error($query, $errno, $error) { 
    die('<font color="#000000"><strong>' . $errno . ' - ' . $error . '<br /><br />' . $query . '<br /><br /><small><font color="#ff0000">[TEP STOP]</font></small><br /><br /></strong></font>');
}
```

Utilização:

```
$data_array = array(
    'nome' => 'Nome',
    'sobrenome' => 'Sobrenome',
    'genero' => 1,
    'email' => 'email@mail.com',
    'fone' => 'null',
    'data' => 'now()');

// insert
tep_db_perform('clientes', $data_array);

// update
tep_db_perform('clientes', $data_array, 'update', "cliente_id = '1'");
```