# Atualização dos dados no banco sem alterar os demais que já existem - PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Oi, estou tentando criar uma página de alteração dos dados cadastrais com banco mysql, porém ele só deverá atualizar os dados que estiverem preenchidos e não alterar os demais dados se já existirem no banco.

Já tentei de mil maneiras e não consigo, poderiam me ajudar?

Segue o código:

```
<?php

try{    
//Abre a conexão; 
    include "conexao.php";  

//Pega os dados do formulário; 

    $campos = array();
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    if(!empty($nome)) $campos[]="nome='$nome'";
    if(!empty($apelido)) $campos[]="apelido='$apelido'";
    if(!empty($telefone)) $campos[]="telefone='$telefone'";
    if(!empty($celular)) $campos[]="celular='$celular'";
    if(!empty($email)) $campos[]="email='$email'";
    if(!empty($endereco)) $campos[]="endereco='$endereco'";
    if(!empty($num_end)) $campos[]="num_end='$num_end'";


//Prepara a query; 
    $stmt = $conn -> prepare("UPDATE `clientes` SET ".implode(',', $campos)." WHERE ID = :id");

//Executa a query;
    $stmt->execute([':id' => $id]);
    echo "Dados atualizados com sucesso! :)";   

} 
//Exibe a mensagem caso dê erro;
    catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $stmt;
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: Se conseguiu resolver, poste a solução na parte das respostas. Alterar a pergunta invalida as respostas já existentes. Reverti sua edição, você pode consultar o histórico aqui para copiar a solução no campo apropriado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/249405/revisions

Comment: Obrigado, sou novo aqui e ainda não sabia dessa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está com dois problemas no seu código, o primeiro é que a cada novo campo, você está substituindo o anterior (conforme informando pelo @rray). Deve utilizar como array:

```
if(!empty($nome)) $campos[] = "nome='$nome'";
```

Entretanto, na hora de realizar o interpolate das suas variáveis na query, está fazendo errado.

Isso:

```
$stmt = $conn -> prepare("UPDATE `clientes` SET '.implode(',','.$campos').' WHERE ID = '.$id'");
```

Deveria ser:

```
$stmt = $conn -> prepare("UPDATE `clientes` SET ".implode(',', $campos)." WHERE ID = '{$id}'");
```

Basicamente, aonde você deveria fechar e abrir string com aspas duplas, está utilizando aspas simples e está adicionado a variável `$campos`, dentro da função implode, como se fosse uma string normal e não uma variável.

Mais informações em:

[PHP: Strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Entretanto, isso deixará seu código vulnerável a SQL injection. Você deveria utilizar prepared statements no lugar:

```
$stmt = $conn -> prepare("UPDATE `clientes` SET ".implode(',', $campos)." WHERE ID = :id");
$stmt->execute([':id' => $id]);
```

Mais informações em

[PHP: SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

**UPDATE**

Existe uma situação que não está sendo tratada no seu código. **E se nenhum campo for alterado?**

Essa situação pode ser facilmente resolvida verificando se existem itens no array:

```
if (count($campos) > 0)
{
    /Prepara a query; 
    $stmt = $conn -> prepare("UPDATE `clientes` SET ".implode(',', $campos)." WHERE ID = :id");

    //Executa a query;
    $stmt->execute([':id' => $id]);
    echo "Dados atualizados com sucesso! :)";  
}
else
{
    echo "Nenhum campo foi modificado";  
}
```

Acredito que esse seja o motivo do seu último erro.

Comment: Tentei fazer da segunda maneira, usando o prepared statements, e retornou: 

**Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ID = '6'' at line 1**

Comment: @RodrigoAlves você já tentou executar a sua query diretamente no SGBD? Atualize seu código para vermos como está e faça um echo da query que é gerada pela string.

Comment: Atualizei o código da forma que está atualmente, desculpe mas não sei fazer essas duas coisas que você pediu, o echo eu tentei fazer mas deu erro :(

Comment: Adicione antes do `execute`. `echo "UPDATE \`clientes\` SET ".implode(',', $campos)." WHERE ID = '{$id}'";` Pegue o código que for printado e execute diretamente no banco.

Comment: @RodrigoAlves atualizei a resposta com um caso que não está sendo tratado.

Comment: Cara, suas informações foram de suma importância para que eu conseguisse encontrar uma maneira de resolver o problema, muitíssimo obrigado, com isso já dei uma pesquisada sobre o .implode que nunca tinha utilizado anteriormente, pessoas como você que a comunidade precisa. Abração!

Comment: Coloquei o código atualizado e funcional com algumas modificações :D

Comment: Só queria comentar o `Entretanto, isso deixará seu código vulnerável a SQL injection. Você deveria utilizar prepared statements no lugar`. Na verdade ele continua com o mesmo problema de `SQL Injection`, já que os parâmetros do `SET` não estão "escapados".

Answer (score 4):

Precisa fazer a atribuição do array de forma correta, atuamente você sobrescreve a string a cada if. Também faltou adicionar as aspas simples de forma correta na hora do `implode()`o ideal era utilizar prepared statements e eliminar esse problema e o de sql injections.

No lugar de:

```
if(!empty($nome)) $campos = "nome='$nome'";
```

Faça (não esqueça dos demais campos):

```
if(!empty($nome)) $campos[] = "nome='$nome'";

//ou se preferir sprintf()
//$set = sprintf("'%s'",implode("','",  $campos));

$set = "'". implode("','",  $campos) ."'";
$stmt = $conn -> prepare("UPDATE `clientes` SET ". $set ." WHERE ID = $id");
```

**Relacionada:**

[Como fazer bind dinâmico PDO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33528/91)

Comment: Ajustei e está retornando:

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\cadastro\alterando2.php on line 29
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''.implode(',','.Array').' WHERE ID = '.6'' at line 1

Comment: @RodrigoAlves editei a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, dei uma pesquisada melhor, mudei algumas coisas mas deu certo, atualizei com o código funcional, abraços! :D

Answer (score 1):

Consegui deixando o código assim:

```
    <?php

    try{    

    //Abre a conexão; 
    include "conexao.php";  

    //Pega os dados do formulário; 
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $campos = array();

    if(!empty($_POST['nome'])){
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $campos[]= "nome='$nome'";
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['apelido'])){
    $apelido = $_POST['apelido'];
    $campos[]="apelido='$apelido'";
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['telefone'])){
    $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
    $campos[]="telefone='$telefone'";
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['celular'])){
    $celular = $_POST['celular'];
    $campos[]="celular='$celular'";
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['email'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $campos[]="email='$email'";
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['$endereco'])){
    $endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
    $campos[]="endereco='$endereco'";
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['num_end'])){  
    $num_end = $_POST['num_end'];   
    $campos[]="num_end='$num_end'";
    }


    //Prepara a query; 
    $stmt = $conn -> prepare("UPDATE `clientes` SET ".implode(',', $campos)." WHERE ID = :id");

    //Executa a query;
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
    echo "Dados atualizados com sucesso! :)";   

    } 
    //Exibe a mensagem caso dê erro;
    catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    ?>
```

Obrigado à todos.

Answer (score -1):

Sua duvida e algo comum no mundo das API's, vou te fala como mais não vou fazer o código(isso fica por sua conta)!
Busque todas as informações no banco de dados, e atualize as informações que foram passadas, as que não foram passadas recebem os valores antigos (e uma forma, existem outras...).

Comment: Obrigado pela dica amigo, consegui por aqui depois de 3 dias tentando haha :D