# Como fazer o bindValue no PHP quando o valor é um array?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou tentando passar mais de um id para pesquisa no meu programa mas a pesquisa só traz um objeto com os dados do primeiro id, Código da consulta em sql:

```
    public static function listar_servidores_ids($id){
    //LISTA SERVIDORES SELECIONADOS

    $pdo    = \Core\DB::getConnection();
    $sql    = 'SELECT * FROM servidores WHERE id IN (?)';
    $stmt   = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $id);
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt-> fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

(Quando eu passo direto os ids ao inves da "?" na consulta ela ocorre normalmente, mas quando eu passo por exemplo '1,2'ao invés de $id no bindValue só retorna o do primeiro id, mesma coisa de quando eu passo os ids via url Exemplo:"http://localhost:8080/index?id/[1,4,3]")
Código do controller que recebe o id e chama a função de consulta no banco:

```
public function execute()
{
    //CHAMA A OPERAÇÃO DE ALTERAR OS DADOS UM SERVIDOR
    $ids = Input::args('id');
    $ids = str_ireplace("[", "", $ids);
    $ids = str_ireplace("]", "", $ids);
    $this->set( 'servidor',    \App\Operacoes::listar_servidores_ids( $ids ) );

}
```

Comment: vc não fazer um bind de um array em cima de uma unica interrogação. Precisa fazer algo como: [Bind dinâmico com prepare](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33524/91)

Answer (score -1):

Se eu entendi sua pergunta, acredito que você deve retornar sua consulta fazendo um `foreach`.

Exemplo:

```
Array (id => 1)

foreach ($array as $key => $value){
   $type = (is_numeric($value) ? \PDO::PARAM_INT : \PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $stmt->bindValue(":{$key), $value, $type);
}
```

Ele vai percorrer todos os arrays separando o índice, valor e o tipo para o `BindValue`.